# In Ohio, what is the speed limit on an on-ramp?

Tags: traffic, speeding, ohio

One time, on a long, straight, downhill on-ramp to an interstate highway, there was a cop pointing his laser at the cars that were going down the ramp on their way to enter the highway. The speed limit on the highway is 65 mph, while the speed limit on the street that the other end of the ramp is connected to is 35 mph, but no speed is posted on the ramp, however, and the cop seemed to be trying to take advantage of that ambiguity, perhaps trying to punish people for reaching the highway's speed limit too early. So what exactly would the speed limit be on such a ramp?

Comment: Are you sure he wasn't clocking people on the highway?  Cops often do this from on ramps so they are (1) not so easy to see from the highway and (2) able to get onto the highway quickly to pull people over.

Comment: His laser was pointing straight up the ramp, away from the highway.

Comment: He was at the end (bottom) of the ramp?

Comment: He was closer to the top of the ramp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically - in fact - in almost all cases - there are no posted, regulatory speed limits for on- and off- ramps.

[This article](http://www.sptimes.com/News/050700/SouthPinellas/A_word_of_advice_on_r.shtml) proved interesting. Specifically,

> Those ramp speed signs, black numerals on a yellow field, are advisory only. They have no force of law. **The only regulatory speed signs are the black-on-white speed limits posted on the roadway itself.**
>
> In other words, if you take a ramp on two wheels, a police officer can ticket you for reckless driving, but if a ramp is posted at 35 mph and you take it at 45 without creating a danger to yourself or others, you can't be ticketed for speeding.

The first signs referred to are signs for the [advisory speed limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advisory_speed_limit). They look like this:

[image]

<sup>From [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/MUTCD_W13-3.svg), listed as an example for highway ramps.</sup>

> . . .
>
> "Why don't they just post those speeds on black-and-white signs, I wonder? Then there would be no doubt."
>
> We wondered, too, so we asked the DOT that very question.
>
> And the answer was, they do it because that's the way it's done all over the country, and **the reason it's done all over the country is that ramps are generally considered too short a distance over which to enforce a speed limit.**

Comment: So why would a cop be checking people's speed on a ramp? I know that in Texas the "advisory" speeds are actually enforceable, so it's not out of the realm of possibility that there's some kind of law in Ohio that the cop was trying to exploit. The ramp in question had no speed signs of any color.

Comment: Note that even if signs are advisory, most (all?) places have a general speed rule that you can't go faster than is safe and reasonable.

Comment: Does that mean a cop can pick a maximum "safe and reasonable" speed out of a hat and then enforce it?

Comment: @cpast it is entirely possible that the cop was actually clocking people on the highway, and sitting at the top of the ramp so he could easily drive onto the highway in order to pull them over.

Comment: @phoog Did you mean to reply to the OP? My comment was not a reply to the OP, but rather a reply to the answer.

Comment: @cpast yes I did.  I read too quickly and thought you were the one who had asked "So why would a cop be checking people's speed on a ramp?"

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million A driver could still be ticketed for aggressive or reckless driving, and there *are* absolute speed limits in Ohio.

Comment: @cpast Yes, there are absolute speed limits in place, and, of course, reckless driving is a ticketable offense.

Comment: @HDE226868 There *are* absolute speed limits, but if there's *also* a "safe and reasonable" speed statute, then they can ticket you for that, no matter how far below the absolute limit you are. That's probably what the "Too fast for conditions" check box is for.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million: If a person is able to operate the vehicle smoothly along a suitable path, that *should* constitute prima facie evidence that the speed of the vehicle was safe and reasonable.  Conversely, an inability to maintain control of the vehicle, even if a person avoids an accident, could be taken as a sign that the speed was not safe and reasonable.  I don't know if any states actually *say* such things in their statutes and regulations, however.

Comment: Maybe the cop knows that there will be people on the ramp that actually exceed the highway speed limit?